# Is there any way to know what is the result of each set of data in Junit and Selenium?

Tags: selenium, junit, automation, data-driven-tests

I'm trying to make tests with a different variation of data but with the same test case (JUnit, Selenium).
I just want to know if there is any way to have the result of each set of data individually as if a set of data failed I want to know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several test classes that run with the Paramerized test runner - org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters. It works very nicely. Here is a good example: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests.

You can specify a piece of the data to be included in the test name during execution. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

With the use of ITestResult you can get result of each individual Test Set,

Sample Code :

```
public void testStatus(ITestResult result) throws IOException
{
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {

        testResult = "Test Fail :" + result.getName();
        System.out.println(testResult);

        testResult = "Details of Fail Testcase:" + result.getThrowable();
        System.out.println(testResult);         

    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {

        testResult = "Test Pass :" + result.getName();          
        System.out.println(testResult);

    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {

        testResult = "Test Skip :" + result.getName();          
        System.out.println(testResult);

    } else {

        testResult = "Test Undefined :" + result.getName() + "<br>Status : " + result.getStatus();          
        System.out.println(testResult);

        testResult = "Details of undefined Testcase:" + result.getThrowable();          
        System.out.println("Test Undefined :" + result.getName() + "<br>Status : " + result.getStatus());
        System.out.println(testResult);
    }       
}
```

Comment: @Mohammed Esa, have you tried with ITestResult ? Please feedback, so it may help to other users as well.